# Running and debugging an ASP.NET Core RC2 application in Docker

Tags: docker, build, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to use Docker in ASP.NET Core RC2 application in VS 2015.

Here are the steps I followed.

1. Create sample application of Type "ASP.NET Core Web Application(.NET Core)".
2. I have added the new Extension in VS 2015 "Docker Tools for Visual Studio 2015 – Preview ".
3. I have added Docker Support in the system and now I am trying to build my application and It gives following 2 issues

> Error Running: powershell -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy
>   RemoteSigned .\DockerTask.ps1 -Build -Environment Debug -Machine ''
>   -ClrDebugVersion VS2015U2. See the output window for details.
>
> Error MSB3073 The command "powershell -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy
>   RemoteSigned .\DockerTask.ps1 -Clean -Environment Debug -Machine ''"
>   exited with code 1.   SFWTravelDesk.Docker

Here is the output window details,

> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: SFWTravelDesk.Docker,
>   Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ 1>  powershell -NonInteractive
>   -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned .\DockerTask.ps1 -Clean -Environment Debug -Machine ''.
>
> 1>  VERBOSE: Setting: $env:CLRDBG_VERSION = "VS2015U2"
>
> 1>  VERBOSE: Setting: $env:REMOTE_DEBUGGING = 0
>
> 1>  VERBOSE: Executing: docker-compose -f
>
> 1>'C:\Users\ssz\Desktop\SFWTravelDesk\SFWTravelDesk.Docker\src\SFWTravelDesk.Docker\docker-compose.debug.yml' -p
>
> 1>  sfwtraveldeskdocker down
>
> 1>  'docker-compose' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>
> 1>  operable program or batch file.
>
> 1>  Clean : Failed to clean up the containers
>
> 1>  At C:\Users\ssz\Desktop\SFWTravelDesk\SFWTravelDesk.Docker\src\SFWTravelDesk.Docker\DockerTask.ps1:467 char:5
>
> 1>  +     Clean
>
> 1>  +     ~~~~~
>
> 1>      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>
> 1>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Clean
>
> 1>C:\Users\ssz\Desktop\SFWTravelDesk\SFWTravelDesk.Docker\src\SFWTravelDesk.Docker\Properties\Docker.targets(61,5): error MSB3073: The command "powershell -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned .\DockerTask.ps1 -Clean -Environment Debug -Machine ''" exited with code 1.
>
> 1>C:\Users\ssz\Desktop\SFWTravelDesk\SFWTravelDesk.Docker\src\SFWTravelDesk.Docker\DockerTask.ps1 : error : Error Running: powershell -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned .\DockerTask.ps1 -Clean -Environment Debug -Machine ''. See the output window for details.
>
> ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Can you please suggest any changes required or I missed anything.

Thanks,
Saurabh